# Binding NSMutableArray to NSPopUpButton and inserting new values

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

(This example project is here https://github.com/danieljfarrell/BindingToPopUpButtons)

I'm just getting into binds, but I have an NSPopUpButton bound to a NSArrayController which is managing a content array in my AppDelegate (model) and all works well! However it only works well for static objects which are added to the content array in the `-init` method. I have problems when I mutate the content array (inserting, adding etc...).

[image: Songs loaded in -init]

```
// AppDelegate.m
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _songs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary *song1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"title" : @"Back in the USSR"}];
        NSMutableDictionary *song2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"title" : @"Yellow Submarine"}];

        [_songs addObjectsFromArray:@[song1, song2]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**Problem**. When I mutate the content array using `-mutableArrayValueForKey:` by inserting a new song the NSPopUpButton displays the `-description` of the array rather than the value of the array elements and also the array seems to be duplicated? For this simple case where the model is just a NSMutableDictionary how can I properly mutate the content array in an KVO compliant way?

[image: Mutating the data source]

```
// AppDelegate action method from button click
- (IBAction)addNewSong:(id)sender {

    // Grab the new song title from a text field
    NSString *newSong = self.songTextField.stringValue;
    // Grab the insert index from a text field.
    NSInteger index = self.indexTextField.integerValue;

    /* Here I want the array controller to
       create a new NSMutableDictionary
       and set the title key with the new song. */
    [[self.songs mutableArrayValueForKey:@"title"] insertObject:newSong atIndex:index];

    /* I also tried adding a dictionary but ran into a similar problem...*/
    // [[self.songs mutableArrayValueForKey:@"title"] insertObject:[@{@"title" : newSong} mutableCopy] atIndex:index]; 
}
```

The bindings for the NSPopUpButton are standard:

- **Content**

  - *Bind to:* Array Controller
  - *Controller key:* arrangedObjects
- **Content Value**

  - *Bind to:* Array Controller
  - *Controller key:* arrangedObjects
  - *Model key path:* title (the key of the NSDictionary items contained in the the arrangedObjects array).

Comment: Why don't you create a NSDictionary and add to the array controller?

Comment: I just updated above. Is this what you meant? Doing that gives a similar situation, you still get a `-description` of the whole array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Volker means create an outlet for you NSArrayController and do something like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *song = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"title": newSong}];

[[self myArrayController] addObject:song];
```